# Regularity of principal curvatures

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth surface with orientation given by the unit normal field $N: S \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$. $N$ is itself smooth, in the sense of smoothness on $S$ as a $2-$manifold.

> Why are the principal curvature smooth (in the sense of manifolds)?

Principal curvatures at $p \in S$ are the eigenvalues of the operator $L_p: T_pS \rightarrow T_pS$, $L_p(v)=-dN_p(v)$, where $dN_p$ is the differential of $N$ at $p$ (in the sense of manifolds).

I know intuitively how the proof should go (?): $L_p$ depends smoothly on $p$ and so do its eigenvalues, hence the principal curvature. 
The last bit is an extension of "roots of a polynomials depends continuously on its coefficients", fact I'm not sure can be extended to "depends smoothly", and I  don't know how to apply here, since I can't translate the dependence of $L_p$ from $p$ into some kind of $2\times 2$ matrix.

I don't know how to proceed since I'm not sure on how to deal with the functions $k_i$. Can you point me to a reference of a proof of this fact, or give me some hint on how to proceed?

---

$f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth in the sense of manifolds if for every parametrization $\phi$ of $S$ we have that $f\circ\phi$ is smooth in the classical way.

$f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth in the sense of manifolds if every component $f_i$ is smooth in the sense of the above definition.

Answer (score 1):

Given a local parametrization of your surface you can express the principal curvatures as a smooth function of the Gaussian and mean curvature, which depend smoothly on the coefficient of the metric and form coefficients.

Namely, if $\phi$ is the parametrization, the matrix $A\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ which represent the endomorphism $dN$ in the coordinate base given by $\phi$ is 
$$ A= - \begin{vmatrix}
 E & F \\
F & G \\
\end{vmatrix}^{-1} \begin{vmatrix}
 e & f \\
f & g \\
\end{vmatrix} $$
where $E, F, G$ and $e, f, g$ are the coefficients of the first and second fundamental form respectively, which depend smoothly on $p$. Now if you take determinant and minus the mean of the trace you get the two curvatures, and finally
$$k_{1,2}=H \pm \sqrt{H^2-K}$$ 
where $K$ is the Gaussian Curvature and $H$ is the mean curvature.
Last thing you need to do is to extend this to the whole surface which should be easy "gluing" everything together using the local parametrization

Edit: As Anthony has pointed out in the comments, this expression, $\textit{a priori}$, is smooth only if you stay away from umbilic points. It is not clear to me actually what happens there, see his comment for further details.

Comment: Your expression is clearly *not* a smooth function of $H,K$ at points where $H^2 = K$...

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought of that. What you say happens at umbilics points and I haven't come up with a way of fixing this. Do you suggest that the curvatures are not (in general) smooth at umbilics points? One thing to notice is that we are asking for smoothness dependency on p and $H$ and $K$ are functions of $p$ so it could be that the expression is not smooth in $H$ and $K$ but is if you explicit everything to get dependency on $p$ (indeed in some nice cases like the sphere the curvatures are constant even if every point is umbilical).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I would expect regularity of principal curvature at umbilic points to be only as good as the regularity of the eigenvalue/spectrum map on the space of $2\times 2$ matrices, which is not very good: it's partially/directionally differentiable but not totally differentiable/$C^1.$ See e.g. Kato's *A Short Introduction to Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*.

Comment: I wanted to give it a try but I remembered I had seen a paper that applies basic tools, linear algebra mainly, to prove this fact in general. Here is the link:https://www.jstor.org/stable/44236421